# Determinant as a denominator

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

One can "define" (up to sign) the determinant as a denominator of the solution of a system of linear equations (Cramer's rule). Then the property that the determinant is a linear function of its rows follows easily. How one can show by elementary methods that for thus defined determinant $\det A=\det A^T$?

Comment: If you convert the matrix to its echolan form without taking any constant from a row then det of the new matrix and det of original matrix will be same. What will be the determinant of the echolan matrix? And if you do the same thing with $A^T$ then what will the det of echolon form of $A^T$?

Comment: The determinant of thus obtained triangle matrix is equal to the product of its diagonal elements. It's not clear for me why these products for $A$ and $A^T$ are the same.

Comment: You are operating required operation. Not the same operation doing for A. Thats why you will get the same result

Comment: Sorry could you be more detailed please

Comment: What is $A^T$ ?